# Warning - incompatible pointer types, how remove?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, uitableview, xcode5.1

I'm using a Custom cell in my `UITableView`, where I receive values from objects what I add to this cell like this:

```
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.ReportTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    StuardReportCustomCell *cell = [_ReportTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *text = cell.MyLabelInCell.text;
```

All working good but I have one warning (this is only 1 warning in all my app) and I want to remove this warning:

```
 incompatible pointer types initializing StuardReportCustomCell with an expression of type 
 UITableviewCell
```

StuardReportCustomCell .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface StuardReportCustomCell : UITableViewCell

@end
```

This is cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

StuardReportCustomCell *Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(!Cell){
    Cell = [[StuardReportCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

Cell.lbNum.text = [lbNum objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
Cell.lbRouteNum.text = [lbRouteNum objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
Cell.lbTime.text = [lbTime objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
Cell.lbCity.text = [lbCity objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
Cell.lbCameIn.text = [lbCameIn objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
Cell.lbIn.text = [lbIn objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
Cell.lbOut.text = [lbOut objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
Cell.lbCameOut.text = [lbCameOut objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return Cell;
}
```

**Solution:**

```
StuardReportCustomCell *cell = (StuardReportCustomCell  *)[_ReportTableView      cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

or

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.ReportTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
NSString *text = [lbTime objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Just type cast `StuardReportCustomCell *cell = (StuardReportCustomCell  *)[_ReportTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

Comment: @MidhunMP That would fix the warning, but it would hide the real problem.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Where in the OP's question did he indicate he was using cell reuse?

Comment: @CrimsonChris Where did he indicate that he was *not* using cell reuse? I mean, cell reuse is what people do, isn't it?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight What makes you think cell reuse is what people do? It's entirely optional. (I agree with you that it is what you _should_ do 99% of the time.)

Comment: @Never_be Please post the rest of your code. We need to see your `ReportTableView`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I try reproduce what you say but nothing changes, all ok.

Comment: @CrimsonChris I add cellForRowAtIndexPath, other standard UITableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of the warning by adding a cast. However, you should not be reading from the text of the cell, because this mixes up the levels of the Model-View-Controller: you should get the value from the model instead.

Therefore, instead of writing, say,

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.ReportTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
StuardReportCustomCell *cell = (StuardReportCustomCell*)[_ReportTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *text = cell.lbTime.text;
```

you should write

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.ReportTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
NSString *text = [lbTime objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```